# Which Android game is this?

Tags: android, game-identification

Which Android game is this?

It seems like a bounce game like Bounce On or something, but the graphics seems to be entirely different.

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is [Leo's Fortune](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.leosfortune&hl=en), available in the Google Play store.

[image: Leo's Fortune]

Comment: i was searching for bounce and bird and all that.. How did you find it?

Comment: I knew I saw this game before, but didn't remember the name, so I searched for "android game blue fuzzy ball" and found [this](http://www.engadget.com/2014/06/27/leos-fortune-looking-for-gold-on-android-next-month/)

Comment: This game is available on Steam now too: http://store.steampowered.com/app/355630/